# AWS MediaConvert - HLS only-audio stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio-streaming, aws-media-convert

I'm struggling a long time now for setting up the following AWS MediaConvert job and I hope I can get some help.

I want to create an HLS stream without any video but with multiple languages to switch between. The Problem is that in the end the streams are not presented as different audio languages, but as different video qualities. I have two .mp3s for input. I removed the video selector and created two audio selectors.
Then I created an Apple HLS output group with two outputs containing audio-only. I defined them as audio-only-variant streams and that's it.

What am I doing wrong? That's how it looks like now.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="program_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="BEsAsDes",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="indexB-Es-As-Des.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="program_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="ADGC",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO,URI="indexA-D-G-C.m3u8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting each audio output's "Audio track type" to 'Audio-only Variant stream' in the Output groups section of your job, and set the container to 'MPEG-2 Transport Stream.' You can optionally also add a "Name Modifier" string to the manifest name and/or a "Segment Modifier" string (such a language code) to the segment names which will be generated.

This should generate a manifest with two playable variants, like this (note the EXT-X-STREAM-INF: tags):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=110953,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=108711,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
indexENG.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=110703,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=109794,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
indexFRA.m3u8
```